# Unable to use label_image.py from the Instructions on the tensorflow for poets

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition

I have retrained the inception model according to instructions from the website

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#4

But I cant find out why in its step 5 I am unable to classify a image by using label_image.py .After following the steps in 5 part. and finally using

`python /tf_files/label_image.py /tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg` in docker, 
I get error message in following image:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqQmk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a copy&paste done wrong for `label_image.py`.
Look into the file and see if it is truly pure python code.